# Pages updated with ISR on Next.js revert to old version when you press back button

Tags: next.js, vercel, sanity

We have set up a headless site with Sanity as CMS, using Next.js 13.1.1 running on Vercel.
After the site is built a user can update a page in Sanity, and using ISR (Incremental Static Regeneration) the updated page is shown on the front end.

Everything seems to work fine, but then we noticed that if a user sees an updated page, navigates to another page, and then returns to the first page with the back button, he will now see the old version of the page.

It appears to revert to the previous build, ignoring the changes. If you press refresh you will once again see the updated page.

So, what is happening here? Is there a different buffer that handles "back" that we also need to update?